# mysql 5.7.19 dumping data does not work(input)

Tags: mysql, version

I am trying input datadump to `mysql.5.7.19`.

I command like below :

```
mysql -uroot -p temp < temp201708.sql
```

my `my.cnf` prints error to `/var/log/mysqld.log`, but I do not see any error log while dumping.

However, when jobs done, I can not find any tables or data in `temp` schema. I think I saw some articles that different mysql versions could be a problem. Is it right?

Currently, I do not know what point is wrong, since there were no error log. What should I look for to solve this problem?

Thanks.

FYI, I do not know what version of mysql which made that dump file, I just received from the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers.

I found the cause.

In the dump file, there are some states like `USE mysql;`, `USE temp;`.

So even though I indicate which schema to put in in command line, 
it just ignore the command line and follow the script.

I found all of my data in `mysql` schema.

==========================

Conclusion

if you dump with some command like below

```
$ > mysqldump -u[user] -p[passwd] [scheme] > dump.sql
```

it is ok with

```
$ > mysql -u[user] -p[passwd] [target_scheme] < dump.sql
```

If not, you should check the contents of `.sql` file.

Comment: I decide to chose my own answer, since other guys answers are missing the point. One of those is out, and the other is in but that contents are already included in the original post. I think considering the contents of dump file is the most appropriate answer for this post

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump -u root -p DatabaseName > /Path-To-put-The-File/fileName.sql

Comment: Thanks but opposite way. I have to input data, not extract.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a dump in mysql:

1. run cmd
2. locate location of your mysql server like

   Enter:
   `cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin`
3. `mysqldump -uUsernameHere -pYourPasswordHere dbnamehere > "D:\sample.sql"` make sure you have a drive `D:` in your computer or you can change it.

> This is working and tested.

You can use it by calling a `.bat` file to execute the command.

Otherwise if you want to store a data into your Database use `mysql` only and not `mysqldump` and change `>` to `<`

like this:

`mysql -uUsernameHere -pYourPasswordHere dbnamehere < "D:\sample.sql"`